# Is it possible to expand the Canvas in Android?

Tags: android, canvas, rendering, custom-view

I have a rotated TextView class whose Canvas I rotate in the onDraw method:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(final Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.save();
    canvas.rotate(-90);
    canvas.translate(-getHeight(), 0);
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.restore();
}
```

The TextView is being positioned and rotated correctly, but the text seems to be getting clipped off:

[image: rotated text view with clipped off text]

How can I expand the `Canvas` correctly such that the `TextView` does not cut the text off?

**Note** the highlight area is the result of drawing the clip bounds of `canvas` right before `super.onDraw(canvas)` so I know the clip region is correct.

Comment: Are you sure it's the canvas at fault?

Comment: Not really, @JesseJ, from exploring - it looks like maybe TextView ignores the size of its Canvas and only uses its layout size. Any suggestions?

Comment: Not really sure. I'm not quite sure why it's even being cut off. What about doing something with TextView, like rotating it?

Answer (score 0):

Of course the text is clipped off!
If you rotate the canvas, you just rotate the drawing inside the `View`, whereas the bounds (which don't depend by `Canvas`, but they're defined by the `View`) aren't rotated.
Therefore you have to rotate the whole `View`, just like the code below:

```
this.setRotation(-90); // 'this' is your view.
```